# Using CMake for cocos2d-x projects

Tags: android, ios, cmake, cross-platform, cocos2d-x

Now I know this question pops-up frequently, but since I could not find a satisfying answer yet, I'm gonna ask here again:

I'd like to setup a cross-platform project for cocos2d-x using cmake.

My intention would be to have the general setup in my CMakeLists.txt files and be able to use this setup for Windows and Mac development at the same time, so I would easily be able to test our progress on Windows Phone, Android, iOS (iPad), Blackberry, etc.

I don't want to drag and drop files to XCode every time I need to deploy the game on the iPad when I applied changes to my Visual Studio solution and vice versa (when a colleague made a change to the XCode project).

Now I found the ios-cmake project [here](https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/downloads/detail?name=ios-cmake.tar.gz&can=2&q=)and the android-cmake [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-cmake/).

Are they any good, i.e. are they still maintained and any good for developing with cocos2d-x?

Has anyone of you gathered any experience using cmake for cocos2d-x development or is there another common way to handle that kind of cross-system development with cocos2d-x? (I know there is the python script for the initial setup, but as I said, i need it to keep the project maintained at any time).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

A year ago, Reuben Bond made a fork to crosscompile cocos2d-x, you can see it [Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/15622). Exist a pull request supported by the official cocos2d-x project [Here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/4071) 3 months ago for Linux only, and another with windows [Here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/4411).

I'm interested on cross-compiling and I hope cocos2d-x V3 support it.